# How can I set expiration for Queues in Activemq if user not subscribed in specific period of time?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

How can I delete queues from activeMQ if user not subscribes , I have a lot of users in system so I think will be performance issue if users not deleted from activeMQ , I am using spring boot and WebSocketConfig, this my implementation:

```
@Service
public  class NotificationWebSocketService {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public void initiateNotification(WebSocketNotification notificationData) throws InterruptedException {

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 20000);

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(notificationData.getUserID(), "/reply", notificationData.getMessage(),headers);

    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

      @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

          config
            .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
            .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue","/user")

            .setRelayHost("localhost")
            .setRelayPort(61613);


        }


        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [destination policy](http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html) for that in the broker config.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">

  <destinationPolicy>
     <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
           <policyEntry queue=">" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000"/>
        </policyEntries>
     </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

</broker>
```

Comment: How can me add this part in my spring boot application , also i using  **WebSocketConfig**

Comment: ` @Override
     public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

    
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
   .setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
   .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue","/user")
   .setRelayHost("localhost")
   .setRelayPort(61613);
    
    
     }`

Comment: give me plz example to implement this

Comment: can you look in this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778137/spring-boot-and-web-socket-with-embedd-activemq